# Why doesn't the vendor folder show in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, laravel, bitbucket

I have a Laravel project. I'm using Git to upload projects into Bitbucket but the vendor folder is not shown. Why not?

All files have been uploaded except the vendor folder.

Comment: Yes vendor folder will not be included because, it is part of `.gitignore` all you have to do is run `composer update` when you clone your repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for privacy purpose it removes some files while pushing on bitbucket.

just open command prompt, and move into clone directory  and run  **composer update** command after pulling from bitbucket

Answer (score 3):

if you want to show your `vendor` folder remove it from `.gitignore` but it is not recommended.

then run `git add .` and commit your change push it to bitbucket.

Comment: And in addition because when you will clone you project in other devices you will install the app via composer and after the installation you will see the vendor folder once again.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.gitignore` file in the root directory of Laravel project has this line:

```
/vendor
```

Git doesn't add this directory to the repository. You shouldn't commit this folder. Each member of your team should run `composer install` command after checkout to download all dependencies to the `vendor` directory on their machine.

Comment: i found this line : /vendor /node_modules /public/storage Homestead.yaml Homestead.json

Comment: These are separate lines. Probably you're using some really bad text editor or something. Try to open this file with Sublime Text, Atom, PHPStorm or something similar.

Comment: oh yes i found it /vendor
i understand now thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There is a file called .gitignore (is hidden) that says to git what files are not needed to upload to the repo (github, bitbucket, etc).

The most likely that in you have a gitignore that points your vendor directory.